# Python Pandas check that string is only "Date" or only "Time" or "Datetime"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, datetime

I am reading a csv using pandas

```
str,date,float,time,datetime
a,10/11/19,1.1,10:30:00,10/11/19 10:30
b,10/11/19,1.2,10:00:00,10/11/19 10:30
c,10/11/19,1.3,11:10:11,10/11/19 10:30
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Now my business requirement is that I want to tell which column is pure date field, pure time field, or which is complete datetime. For particular column my code is:

```
try:
                    dt = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
                    dates = [obj.date() for obj in dt]
                    times = [obj.time() for obj in dt]

                    if dates and (set(times) == set([datetime.time(0, 0)])):
                        # Its a pure date field
                    elif <something>:
                       # Its a  pure time field
                    else:
                       #Its a Datetime field


except:
            # its not a datefield
```

problem with my code is when there is only time field, pd.to_datetime is taking default today's date so I am not able to differentiate it with datetime. Is there any easy solution? Please help me fill "something" in code above

Comment: Please add some of that data too, so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have added the sample data @AKX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If want test times, pandas by default use today dates, so possible solution is test them with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), [`Timestamp.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html) and [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) if all values of column match.

Also added another solution for test dates - test if same values after removed times by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2019-01-01 12:23:10',
                        '2019-01-02 12:23:10'],
                   'b':['2019-01-01',
                        '2019-01-02'],
                   'c':['12:23:10',
                        '15:23:10'],
                   'd':['a','b']})
print (df)
                     a           b         c  d
0  2019-01-01 12:23:10  2019-01-01  12:23:10  a
1  2019-01-02 12:23:10  2019-01-02  15:23:10  b

def check(col):
    try:
        dt = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

        if (dt.dt.floor('d') == dt).all():
            return ('Its a pure date field')
        elif (dt.dt.date == pd.Timestamp('now').date()).all():
            return ('Its a pure time field')
        else:
            return ('Its a Datetime field') 
    except:
        return ('its not a datefield')


print (check('a'))
print (check('b'))
print (check('c'))
print (check('d'))
Its a Datetime field
Its a pure date field
Its a pure time field
its not a datefield
```

---

Another idea is also test if numeric columns and by default return not numeric for prevent casting numeric to datetimes, but if possible all datetimes contains only todays dates (`f` column) then test  for times is different with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for match pattern `HH:MM:SS` or `H:MM:SS`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['2019-01-01 12:23:10',
                        '2019-01-02'],
                   'b':['2019-01-01',
                        '2019-01-02'],
                   'c':['12:23:10',
                        '15:23:10'],
                   'd':['a','b'],
                   'e':[1,2],
                  'f':['2019-11-13 12:23:10',
                       '2019-11-13'],})
print (df)
                     a           b         c  d  e                    f
0  2019-01-01 12:23:10  2019-01-01  12:23:10  a  1  2019-11-13 12:23:10
1           2019-01-02  2019-01-02  15:23:10  b  2           2019-11-13
```

---

```
def check(col):
    if np.issubdtype(df[col].dtype, np.number):
        return ('its not a datefield')

    try:
        dt = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
        if (dt.dt.floor('d') == dt).all():
            return ('Its a pure date field')
        elif df[col].str.contains(r"^\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$").all():
            return ('Its a pure time field')
        else:
            return ('Its a Datetime field') 
    except:
        return ('its not a datefield')


print (check('a'))
print (check('b'))
print (check('c'))
print (check('d'))
print (check('e'))
print (check('f'))
Its a Datetime field
Its a pure date field
Its a pure time field
its not a datefield
its not a datefield
Its a Datetime field
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans, it is working. My doubt is if my "datetime" columns contains today's date with some time , then will it return ('Its a pure time field'). Am I right?