# Easiest way to determine whether column in pandas Dataframe contains DATE or DATETIME information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following DF:

```
  col1         col2
1 2017-01-03   2018-03-30 08:01:32
2 2017-01-04   2018-03-30 08:02:32
```

If I do `df.dtypes`, I get get the following output:

```
col1    datetime64[ns]
col2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Howeverm `col1` contains Only Date information (DATE), whereas `col2` contains both date and time information (DATETIME).

Whats the easiest way to determine wheter a column contains DATE or DATETIME information?

Data generation:

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate the df
col1 = ["2017-01-03", "2017-01-04"]
col2 = ["2018-03-30 08:01:32", "2018-03-30 08:02:32"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": col1, "col2": col2})

df["col1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col1"])
df["col2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col2"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831943/python-pandas-check-that-string-is-only-date-or-only-time-or-datetime/58832144#58832144) SO Question, the following function could do the job:

```
def check_col(col):
    try:
        dt = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
        if (dt.dt.floor('d') == dt).all():
            return('Its a DATE field')
        else:
            return('Its a DATETIME field')
    except:
        return("could not parse to pandas datetime")
```

However, isn't there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def col_has_time(col):
    dt = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    return (dt.hour == 0).all()
```

Comment: The logic is similar to the function I presented above...your function checks whether the hour attribute of all timestamps have the same value (i.e. zero) and my function checks whether all dates are the same if you cut off the time information (simplyfied). For me, both ways are *indirect*. I was hoping for an inbuilt pandas function (or something similar)